# Variable declarations in OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop, variables

Is it necessary to declare variables in PHP at the class scope before using them with a $this->variable reference?  Or is $this->variable usage enough to declare the a class variable within a method?

For example using:

```
class MyClass {

  public function setName($name) {
      $this->myName = $name;
  }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
class MyClass {
public $myName;

  public function setName($name) {
      $this->myName = $name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just try it out and see if it works? If it doesn't throw an error and you can assign and read values, it works. On the other hand, initializing variables is always the cleaner way, even if it isn't required in PHP. So why not going for the safest way?

Comment: How will PHP know if you want the variable to be  `public` or `private` ?

Comment: No, but it's considered best practice. You get to add visibility (you don't want everything public), type and phpdoc, and you get a good overview of what properties are in the class. This might also help your IDE to figure out how your classes work.

Comment: On a side note, not declaring it means you won't be able to enumerate it until assigned, and it won't be visible to various reflection API's.

Comment: @jiml Thanks this is what I was hoping.

Comment: @connum I am working with a premade class inside of a framework and I rather not tinker where I don't have to.

Comment: @AustinLeatham no you should never do any changes to 3rd party code. If you need to change it you should extend it and override or add stuff in your own code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not necessary.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

The functions `__get()` and `__set()` are used when trying to access these variables.

This can have some unexpected behavior, for instance, if you have a private variable `private $test;` and you try to access `$obj->test` you will receive a warning since this variable is not accessible outside the class.

In this same instance, if the variable was not defined but you set it with `$this->test = 5`, you'd then be able to access it with `$var = $this->test;`.

IDE's typically will not resolve these variables but some let you use the phpdocs to help with auto code completion.

Ex:
`/* @var Object $test */`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this isn't really a good idea or best practice. But it can be done https://ideone.com/R2uGva

```
<?php
class MyClass {

  public function setName($name) {
      $this->myName = $name;
  }
}

$kevin = new MyClass;
$kevin->setName('kevin');
var_dump($kevin);
```